# VB WPF textblock.text equal a text file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textblock

In VB2010 WPF, i have a textblock which, when the window loads, i need the text inside the textblock to be the same as the text in an outside .txt file. How can i do this?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: In the window load event handler, you open the text file, read the contents, and copy them into the TextBlock. At which step exactly do you need help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind WPF TextBlock to text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995325/bind-wpf-textblock-to-text-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Window 
    ...
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    ...
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" .../>
    ...
</Window>
```

and...

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
}
```