# WPF TextBlock Binding to a String

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to bind a TextBlock to a string which takes its value from a txt file. The string is correctly filled but its contents are not displayed.

*Class file:*

```
public partial class JokesMessageBox : Window
    {
        public JokesMessageBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Joke { get; set; }
        public string path = "data/jokes.txt";

        public void ReadFile(string path)
        {
            Joke = File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
    }
```

*XAML:*

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,10,0,0"
 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Joke}" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Height="60" Width="309"/>
```

EDIT:

*In the MainWindow class:*

```
 private void btnJokesFirstScreen_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
  JokesMessageBox jkb = new JokesMessageBox();
                jkb.Show();
                jkb.ReadFile("data/jokes.txt");
        }
```

I spent 3+ hours on google, youtube, MSDN, StackOverflow and still can't get it working. What am I missing?

Comment: How/when is `ReadFile` called?

Comment: call readfile in constructor

Comment: I will recomend you to read a little about `DataBinding`.

Comment: I added where the ReadFile() is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the you need to update the binding, the property `Joke` must be a `DependencyProperty` or the `Windows` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

On the view, the binding needs to know `Source`.

Example #1 (Using `DependencyProperty`):

```
public partial class JokesMessageBox : Window
{
    public JokesMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ReadFile(Path); //example call
    }

    public string Joke
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(JokeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JokeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty JokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Joke", typeof(string), typeof(JokesMessageBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public const string Path = "data/jokes.txt";

    public void ReadFile(string path)
    {
        Joke = File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
}
```

Example #2 (Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface):

```
public partial class JokesMessageBox : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public JokesMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ReadFile(Path); //example call
    }

    private string _joke;

    public string Joke
    {
        get { return _joke; }
        set
        {
            if (string.Equals(value, _joke))
                return;
            _joke = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Joke");
        }
    }

    public const string Path = "data/jokes.txt";

    public void ReadFile(string path)
    {
        Joke = File.ReadAllText(path);
    }


    //INotifyPropertyChanged members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the view (XAML partial):

```
...
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,10,0,0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Joke,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="60" Width="309"/>
...
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked! I went with the second example.
 After I had read this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995325/bind-wpf-textblock-to-text-file) I thought it would be something quick and easy.
Now I looked at the other similar problems other people had posted and I noticed this INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I'll look into it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you read the contents of the file, you assign the read string to your `Joke` property:

```
Joke = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

The [`Text` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [`TextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is indeed bound to that property (*if* you have properly set the [data context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
Text="{Binding Joke}"
```

However, what is missing is that the binding cannot possibly have any idea that the property value has changed. You need to **issue a notification** about the property change.

There are two ways to do this that will be recognized by WPF bindings:

- You declare your `Joke` property as a [dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is based on some WPF infrastructure that automatically issues the change notifications.
- You have your class implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here, you have to implement a simple interface with a [`PropertyChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), which you have to fire in your property setter while passing the name of the property as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface. So when you change property Joke TextBlock is not updated. I would do something like this:

```
public partial class JokesMessageBox : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public JokesMessageBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Joke { get; set; }
        public string path = "data/jokes.txt";

        public void ReadFile(string path)
        {
            Joke = File.ReadAllText(path);
            OnPropertyChanged("Joke");
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

I would also suggest you to read about [MVVM patern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).