# Bind to resource text file

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, text-files

I want to bind to a text block to a text file which is compiled as a resource. Is there a way to bind it like a image with the source property and a pack uri?

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Properties/..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you certainly can't do it exactly the same way. If you try this:

```
<TextBox Text="pack://application:,,,/Properties/..."/>
```

...it just displays the pack uri as text -- not what you want.

One possible solution is to create your own `MarkupExtension`. For example:

```
public class TextExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly string fileName;

    public TextExtension(string fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Error handling omitted
        var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + fileName);
        using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage from XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WPF">
    <TextBlock Text="{wpf:Text 'Assets/Data.txt'}" />
</Window>
```

Assuming, of course, that the named text file is a resource:

[image]

Further reading:

- [Markup Extensions for XAML Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MarkupExtension Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Should I handle a IO/Exception there and omit all exceptions?

Comment: I'd think so, yes. I don't see anywhere else you might have a chance to do so.